# Como implementar un menú Navigation Drawer con actividades

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Quería saber si hay una forma de que al hacer click en un ítem del menú me lleve a una actividad, ya lo sé hacer con fragmentos, pero necesito que me lleve a un activity

Codigo de la clase principal

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,                 DiezFrut.OnFragmentInteractionListener  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, new DiezFrut()).commit();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    Fragment fragment= null;

    boolean fragmentTransaction = false;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.diez_frutas) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Unoo_Cerezas.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if (fragmentTransaction)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,fragment).commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
  }
```

Comment: sólo debes cambiar el código q dices saber para fragment por intents `startActivity(new Intent(PrimerActivity.this, SegundoActivity.class));`

Comment: Por favor podrías añadir tu código donde deseas ir a un activity, para así poder ayudarte mejor y la pregunta sea mas objetiva

Comment: @FelixBeeb ya añadi el codigo, Gracias

Comment: @marlonpya, lo que pasa es que si hago eso, al ir al activity se pierde el cajon de naviegacion (menu)

Comment: @Sergio claro es una de las razones que no deberías usar actividades, de otro modo no te queda de otra que crear otro navegador. Yo una vez estuve pensando realizar ésto de navegador con actividades pero nunca lo hice xq es todo un embrollo.

Comment: @marlonpya lo que pasa es que lo estaba tratando con fragments, pero tenia un error y era el siguiente. Cuando hacia click en un item del menu me llevaba al siguiente fragment, y ahi habia un ListView, el cual queria que al hacer click en un item de la lista  me llevara a otro fragment, pero no obtuve ayuda, si me pudieras ayudar te puedo comentar el link de la pregunta acerca del problema.

Comment: @Sergio No ps lo que debes hacer es ir de un fragment hacía una actividad. Para que no compliques ya luego trata de entender bien el código de Andar de fragment en fragment.

Comment: @marlonpya si crees que tienes una respuesta, publicalo como respuesta por favor. Los comentarios son para aclarar detalles de la pregunta o respuesta. Si resulta qque hay malentendidos, siempre se puede retirar o editar la respuesta. Trata de recordar que una pregunta y sus respuestas deberían seguir teniendo sentido cuando el problema esta solucionado.

Comment: @Sergio
Ya sergio tines un navegador con fragmentos perfecto, ahora en cada fragmento debes tener una lista entonces al momento de clickear mándalo a una actividad donde muestre los detalles, si te complica fragmentos no lo hagas, pero ya es desafío tuyo aprenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

> Quería saber si hay una forma de que al hacer click en un ítem del
>   menú me lleve a una actividad, ya lo sé hacer con fragmentos, pero
>   necesito que me lleve a un activity

@Sergio la solución es como Mark Dev lo muestra en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45164/95)

Quisiera comentarte que si deseas realizarlo de la forma que indicas en tu pregunta, deberías preguntarte :

- ¿En cada `Activity` agregarías el `Navigation Drawer`? esto sería repetir código innecesariamente.
- ¿Al abrir una nueva `Activity` al seleccionar una opción desde el `Navigation Drawer` conservarias la `Activity` Anterior? si la conservas y realizas un almacenamiento en pila de las mismas puedes tener problemas de memoria.
- ¿Al abrir una nueva `Activity` al seleccionar una opción desde el `Navigation Drawer` terminarias la `Activity` Anterior? Tal vez esta navegación no provoque problemas pero sería un poco extraña ya que no tendría una Activity principal.

Considero que lo ideal, es como mencionas lo sabes realizar tener un `MainActivity` que tenga un `Navigation Drawer`, al seleccionar un elemento cambias el Fragmento con contenido diferente y siempre tienes el mismo menú.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta posible solución!!!!

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent i;
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.opcion1:
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.opcion2:
             i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.opcion3:
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity3.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;

    }

DrawerLayout drawer=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
}
```